# How do I add a windows 8 user to Linux standalone SAMBA server

Tags: server, windows, permissions

I would like to add a Windows 8 (Microsoft account) user to a SAMBA user on standalone (not domain) linux server, however I do not know how the Microsoft account maps to linux. I have also setup the samba shares based on group access.

I have guests enabled in SAMBA so when my Windows 8 workstation connected for the first time it did not recognise the user and connected to SAMBA as a guest with nobody as user. Now when I connect to the shares it always connects as guest (that is nobody user on SAMBA).
I would like the guest users to still be allowed to connect as read only.
Is there anyway to force Windows 8 to prompt for login again? Note that my shares are not mapped in explorer they are browsable.

Comment: The user on Windows 8 is: `User` but on linux it's `user`. How do I map it without creating another linux account?

Comment: A Windows 8 account is not a Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a central windows server with central user profiles (active directory). To integrate these workstations you have to mount the user home directories into `/home` on your linux machines and hook up the active directory into linux.

The keywords that you want to search for are: **ldap pam active directory integration**.  Useful links:

- [Ubuntu Active Directory Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto)
- [Debian LDAP/PAM](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM)

note that integrating a windows machine into linux/ldap is generally not recommended (unless you have lots and lots of spare time on your hands). It might work satisfactorily with Samba 4.0. I haven't tried since it provides its own ldap...

**Edit**: I think I might have misunderstood you. If you want to access a linux samba share from windows simply follow the [Ubuntu Samba Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide). If you want to login with as $user to the server simply create $user on the server. And set a samba password for the user:

```
smbpasswd -a $user
```

the configure the samba server according to your needs. Note: You don't need ldap/kerberos for this kind of setup. It usually helps to use your windows username and password as username/password for the linux user $user. In that case you won't need to configure any passwords on Windows.

Comment: I am not using Active Directory. This is a home server.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this but I might need it myself soon. Maybe [this link](http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/498804-samba-and-windows-8-1-login) could help you? For future reference I'll copy the proposed solution here as well.

Add a line in /etc/samba/smbusers of the form:

```
linux_name = windows_name1 windows_name2 <etc.>

e.g.
a_user = a_user@hotmail.com
```

This maps Windows name(s) (i.e. your Microsoft account used to log on to Windows 8) to a linux name (i.e. an existing linux & samba account). You may also need to add this parameter to the [global] section of: /etc/samba/smb.conf.

```
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
```

To test the configuration use the following command:

```
testparm -vs | grep "username map"
```

Let me know if you got it to work!